# entity framework not finding connection string

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I'm having an issue with a website I'm building. I can get data to show on the screen without a problem, but when I have the site write back to the database I get the following error:

No connection string named 'MyApplication' could be found in the application config file.

So I did some searching and found that should help if I change this:

```
    public TP90Entities()
        : base("name=TP90Entities")
    {
    }
```

to this:

```
    public TP90Entities()
        : base("TP90Entities")
    {
    }
```

If I do that I get the following error:

> Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode. To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity Framework connection string is specified in the config file of executing application. To use these classes, that were generated from Database First or Model First, with Code First add any additional configuration using attributes or the DbModelBuilder API and then remove the code that throws this exception.

I've rebuild the data connection several times trying to follow the database first method. Also I've upgraded the project to Entity Framework 5. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How does your connection string look like? Do you have the connection string defined in the configuration file of the executable application (.exe.config or web.config)?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I was out of the office. The connection string is contained within the app.config of the entity project. Here's the connection string format `code`<add name="TP90Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TP90.csdl|res://*/Models.TP90.ssdl|res://*/Models.TP90.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=devdatabase;initial catalog=Database;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`code`

Comment: The connection string must be contained within configuration of executable project / web. If it is only in class library it is not found at runtime.

Comment: I fought with that for far too long for something that simple... Can you recommend a book or a website I could use to study Entity framework so I don't have to bug you guys with simple questions?